# Como deserializar un json en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Hola consumiendo una API me devuelve el siguiente json:

```
[
true,
"Data_{7CC0CE00-A688-4A57-B7ED-5EBE70A8057F}",
{
    "sQLEncryptedPassword": "",
    "sQLDecryptedPassword": "PassWord",
    "activeDirectoryDNBase": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "ActiveDirectoryDNBase",
        "required": false,
        "length": 60,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "activeDirectoryDomain": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "ActiveDirectoryDomain",
        "required": false,
        "length": 50,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "activeDirectoryHost": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "ActiveDirectoryHost",
        "required": false,
        "length": 50,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "aDDRESS1": {
        "oldValue": "3901 GEORGIA ST NE",
        "fieldName": "ADDRESS1",
        "required": false,
        "length": 30,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "3901 GEORGIA ST NE"
    },
    "aDDRESS2": {
        "oldValue": "SUITE A4",
        "fieldName": "ADDRESS2",
        "required": false,
        "length": 30,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "SUITE A4"
    },
    "cITY": {
        "oldValue": "ALUQUERQUE",
        "fieldName": "CITY",
        "required": false,
        "length": 25,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "ALUQUERQUE"
    },
    "cOMPANY": {
        "oldValue": "THE ENHANCEMENT CENTER",
        "fieldName": "COMPANY",
        "required": false,
        "length": 30,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "THE ENHANCEMENT CENTER"
    },
    "cOMPORT": {
        "value": 0,
        "oldValue": 0,
        "fieldName": "COMPORT",
        "required": false,
        "length": 4,
        "dataType": "Integer",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "concurrentLimit": {
        "value": 3,
        "oldValue": 3,
        "fieldName": "ConcurrentLimit",
        "required": false,
        "length": 2,
        "dataType": "Integer",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "cONTACT": {
        "oldValue": "JIM SHOTWELL",
        "fieldName": "CONTACT",
        "required": false,
        "length": 30,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "JIM SHOTWELL"
    },
    "cOUNTRY": {
        "oldValue": "United States",
        "fieldName": "COUNTRY",
        "required": false,
        "length": 25,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "United States"
    },
    "defaultUserIdAdTemplate": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "DefaultUserIdAdTemplate",
        "required": false,
        "length": 6,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "eIN": {
        "oldValue": "850483530",
        "fieldName": "EIN",
        "required": false,
        "length": 15,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "850483530"
    },
    "fAX": {
        "oldValue": "(505)891-1768",
        "fieldName": "FAX",
        "required": false,
        "length": 15,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "(505)891-1768"
    },
    "ignoreReadOnly": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "IgnoreReadOnly",
        "required": false,
        "length": 1,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "language": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "Language",
        "required": false,
        "length": 15,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "maskSSN": {
        "oldValue": "Y",
        "fieldName": "MaskSSN",
        "required": false,
        "length": 1,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "Y"
    },
    "passwordDays": {
        "value": 90,
        "oldValue": 90,
        "fieldName": "PasswordDays",
        "required": false,
        "length": 4,
        "dataType": "Integer",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "paymentDueDate": {
        "value": "1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "oldValue": "1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "fieldName": "PaymentDueDate",
        "required": false,
        "length": 8,
        "dataType": "TDateTime",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "sessionTimeout": {
        "value": 30,
        "oldValue": 30,
        "fieldName": "SessionTimeout",
        "required": false,
        "length": 2,
        "dataType": "Integer",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "sQLPASSWORD": {
        "oldValue": "IizCfqe",
        "fieldName": "SQLPASSWORD",
        "required": false,
        "length": 32,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "IizCfqe"
    },
    "sTATE": {
        "oldValue": "NM",
        "fieldName": "STATE",
        "required": false,
        "length": 2,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "NM"
    },
    "syncUserGroupsAD": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "SyncUserGroupsAD",
        "required": false,
        "length": 1,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "tELEPHONE": {
        "oldValue": "(505)891-1583",
        "fieldName": "TELEPHONE",
        "required": false,
        "length": 15,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "(505)891-1583"
    },
    "timeInterval": {
        "value": 0,
        "oldValue": 0,
        "fieldName": "TimeInterval",
        "required": false,
        "length": 4,
        "dataType": "Integer",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "useActiveDirectoryAuth": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "UseActiveDirectoryAuth",
        "required": false,
        "length": 1,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "useBillingEntity": {
        "oldValue": "",
        "fieldName": "UseBillingEntity",
        "required": false,
        "length": 1,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": ""
    },
    "userID": {
        "oldValue": "sa",
        "fieldName": "UserID",
        "required": false,
        "length": 32,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "sa"
    },
    "useZipCodeAPI": {
        "oldValue": "Y",
        "fieldName": "UseZipCodeAPI",
        "required": false,
        "length": 1,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "Y"
    },
    "zIP": {
        "oldValue": "87110-1391",
        "fieldName": "ZIP",
        "required": false,
        "length": 10,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "87110-1391"
    },
    "zipCodeAPIUrl": {
        "oldValue": "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll",
        "fieldName": "ZipCodeAPIUrl",
        "required": false,
        "length": 250,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll"
    },
    "zipCodeAPIUser": {
        "oldValue": "022MEDEZ3885",
        "fieldName": "ZipCodeAPIUser",
        "required": false,
        "length": 24,
        "dataType": "string",
        "isCalCulated": false,
        "isKey": false,
        "isAssigned": true,
        "isNull": false,
        "value": "022MEDEZ3885"
    },
    "aRecordCount": 0,
    "recPerPage": 30,
    "offsetCount": 1,
    "nextCount": 30,
    "doPagination": false,
    "allowBlankIncremental": false,
    "isMainViewWithCompositeData": "N",
    "sortedString": "",
    "fCopyofTableName": "Medez_Data..MdCo0001",
    "fViewName": "",
    "isModified": false,
    "fStoredProc": "",
    "orderBy": "",
    "connectionToken": "Login_{A92EF65C-1DEA-4B39-890E-D7E017D3593A}",
    "connectionType": "P",
    "objectDescription": "Company setup",
    "blobFieldValuePairs": "",
    "tableName": "Medez_Data..MdCo0001",
    "tempTableName": "",
    "objectCount": 0
},
"{BB512B9A-7E08-4478-9F5F-D0093FDFE48E}"
```

]

Estoy Usando RestSharp para consumir la api y he intentado lo siguiente sin resultados:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var result_str = response.Content;
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TmdzCompanySetUpObjExt>(result_str);
```

Comment: ¿Te genera algún error? Cuál es el inconveniente? Podrías colocar el código de la clase TmdzCompanySetUpObjExt?

Answer (score 1):

Primero te diría que vuelques el contenido del JSON en un parser online, para verlo más amigablemente. Por ejemplo, https://jsonparseronline.com/

Allí verás más claramente las propiedades y valores del JSON:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicionalmente, también puedes probar volcar el contenido en un sitio como https://www.jsonutils.com/ y te genera automáticamente el código C# con las clases para poder mapearlo, que *debería* coincidir con tu clase `TmdzCompanySetUpObjExt` pero justamente ahí tienes un buen punto de comparación, y detectar si tu clase está incorrecta.

De hecho, este último sitio no podrá generar el código C# porque el JSON no respeta el formato correcto. A tu JSON le falta declararle los nombres de 3 propiedades que están faltando, sólo están presente sus valores, siendo estos:

- true
- "Data_{7CC0CE00-A688-4A57-B7ED-5EBE70A8057F}"
- "{BB512B9A-7E08-4478-9F5F-D0093FDFE48E}"

Fijate que todo el gran resto del JSON sí está bien conformado.
Aquí debajo por las dudas te pongo un ejemplo de lo que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Espero te sirva!

Comment: No le faltan los nombre de 3 propiedades porque es un array.

Comment: Estaba explicandoselo lo más sencillo posible. Es un JSON *válido* , siendo un array de elementos no heterogéneos, por lo cual se le va a dificular deserializar a una clase tipada así como lo tiene.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes un array heterogeneo de datos; por lo que no puedes deserializar a una clase (`TmdzCompanySetUpObjExt`) ni a una Lista fuertemente tipada de ninguna estructura tuya propia asi a pelo.

Puedes deserializar a un System.Collections.Generic.List usando [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) siempre y cuando T sea un tipo covariante de todos los tipos que tienes en el array.

p.e.:

```
var result_str = @"[
true,
""Data_{7CC0CE00-A688-4A57-B7ED-5EBE70A8057F}"",
{
    ""required"": false,
    ""length"": 50,
},
""{BB512B9A-7E08-4478-9F5F-D0093FDFE48E}""
]";
var objLst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(result_str);
```

Si inspeccionas `objLst` en el depurador veras que:

- `objLst[0]` es object{bool}
- `objLst[2]` es object{string}
- `objLst[2]` es object {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
- `objLst[3]` es object{string}

[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) es una estructura que te permite acceder a los campos. Es la sustitución sin perdida de rendimiento del [DynamicObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.8) que es lo que se usaba antes para este tipo de situaciones.

Esta es la solucion chapucera. Para hacerlo mejor, Newtonsoft.Json ofrece mucha flexibilidad a la hora de serializar y deserializar; p.e.: usar un [CustomCreationConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm).

Te recomiendo que le pegues un buen vistazo a la documentación de Newtonsoft.Json para que te hagas una idea de todas la posibilidades que tienes y seguro que encuentras una solucion consistente y bien hecha a tu problema.

Comment: Newtonsoft está siendo reevaluado por su desempelo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes tener en cuenta los mejores deserializadores.

Este es un ejemplo de Utf8json, es 4 veces más rápido que NewtonSoft (el más cual es más popular), pero maneja mejor la memoria por su "directa serialización"

Este ejemplo usa un tyr para evitar errores, en caso de error retorna null

Este método es un método genérico para deserializar lo que desees.

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    try
    {
        return Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MetodoDeError(e.Message);
        return default;
    }
}
```

Más adelante debes usar esto:

```
List<object> raizJson = Deserialize<List<object>>(result_str);
```

Luego podrás hacer un cast a cada objeto que hagas.

así:

```
if (raizJson.GetType()==typeof(string))
{
  string value = (string)raizJson; // usar raizJson.toString(), podría ser más lento bajo ciertas circustancias.
}
else
{

}
```

Mira la siguiente referencia, cuanto más alta sea la barra indica que demora más, lo cual es peor.

https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2019/09/29/net-serialization-benchmark-2019-roundup/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cual es el error?